# BDD in WPF/.NET

Tags: wpf, bdd

I've just found Swinger (http://github.com/demetriusnunes/swinger) and I was wondering: is there something like this for WPF?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking, try either White ( http://white.codeplex.com/ ) or WiPFlash ( http://code.google.com/p/wipflash ).

If you go for WiPFlash, and you're finding things with anything other than the automation id ('Name' on your WPF component), it's about to change a bit, so maybe hold off for 0.2. Should be out this weekend. Any questions / requests, please post a bug!

Answer (score 0):

And if you're *still* still looking, you could try Bewildr ( https://github.com/natritmeyer/bewildr ). I wrote up an example of using it to do BDD here: http://www.natontesting.com/2011/08/27/step-by-step-example-of-bdding-a-wpf-app-with-cucumber-rspec-ironruby-and-bewildr/